# Deleting Specific Files and then Extract them into another folder

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

With the following code I am trying to delete specific files inside of a folder on a flash drive, and then copy the remaining files into a separate folder. When the program runs and I initiate the button to do so, the program deletes files that have not been modified within the past year, but then it does not continue to extract the remaining files and place them into a separate folder.

Does anyone know why?

```
Imports System.IO

Public Class frmExtractionator

    Dim txtFiles1 As Control

    Private Sub btnStart_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnStart.Click

        Dim sourceDirectory As String = "E:\CopierFolderforTestDriveCapstone"
        Dim archiveDirectory As String = "E:\FilesExtracted"

        Try
            DeleteUnmodifiedFiles(sourceDirectory, 365)

            Dim txtFiles = Directory.EnumerateFiles(sourceDirectory)

            If (Not System.IO.Directory.Exists(archiveDirectory)) Then
                System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(archiveDirectory)
            End If

            For Each currentFileLoc As String In txtFiles
                Dim fileName = currentFileLoc.Substring(sourceDirectory.Length + 1)
                File.Move(currentFileLoc, Path.Combine(archiveDirectory, fileName))
            Next
        Catch eT As Exception
            Console.WriteLine(eT.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub DeleteUnmodifiedFiles(ByVal directoryName As String, ByVal modificationThresholdDays As Integer)
        Dim folder As New DirectoryInfo(directoryName)
        Dim thresholdDate As Date
        Dim wasModifiedSinceThreshold As Boolean
        For Each file As FileInfo In folder.GetFiles
            thresholdDate = DateTime.Now().AddDays(-1 * modificationThresholdDays)
            wasModifiedSinceThreshold = (file.LastWriteTime > thresholdDate)
            If (Not wasModifiedSinceThreshold) Then file.Delete()
        Next
        MessageBox.Show("Deleting Files")
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: As first Step I would add  **Option Strict On**  and set some debug breakpoints, to check which command did not work

Answer (score 1):

This will delete any file in the source directory that hasn't been modified for a year, and then will move any remaining files to the destination directory...

```
Private Sub btnStart_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnStart.Click
    Dim fileListA() As String
    fileListA = (IO.Directory.GetFiles("C:\Scource_Directory"))
    For Each i As String In fileListA
        If (IO.File.GetLastWriteTime(i).ToShortDateString.Substring(6)) < (CType(DateTime.Now.Year.ToString, Integer) - 1) Then
            IO.File.Delete(i)
        End If
    Next
    Dim fileListB() As String
    fileListB = (IO.Directory.GetFiles("C:\Scource_Directory"))
    For Each i As String In fileListB
        IO.File.Move(i, "Destination_Directory")
    Next
End Sub
```